# CodeIgniter 3: undefined method CI_Form_validation::setrules()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create a simple login process using CodeIgniter 3. However, I am getting this error every time I click submit on the login form:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::setrules()
>
> Filename: controllers/Login.php
>
> Line Number: 33
>
> Backtrace:

This is my controller code:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('login_model');

}

public function index()
{
    if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
    {
        $this->load->view('template');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}

public function auth_user()
{
    $this->form_validation->setrules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->setrules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        echo 'IT WORKS';
        $data = array(
          'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
          'password' => $this->input->post('pass')
        );
        //check user credentials
        $result = $this->login_model->login($data);

        if($result == TRUE)
        {   //get user info
            $session_data = array(
                'username' => $result[0]->username
            );
            $user_id = $result->staffID;
            $this->login_model->staff_logs($user_id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged',$session_data);
            $this->load->view('template');
        }
    }else{
        echo 'IT not work';
    }
}
}
```

I am using PHPStorm, when I hover **form_validation**, it says that Field 'form_validation' not found in class Login.

Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the  ***_***  from set_rules(....)

change your code to

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

from

```
    $this->form_validation->setrules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->setrules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```